# Unable to convert String to List in Java using RegEx...!

Tags: java

I am trying to convert the below string to a list in Java, but its taking as a single object, I need four separate list obejcts.

String:
 button 1 of window "abc" of application process "xyz"
    button 2 of window "abc" of application process "xyz"
    button 3 of window "abc" of application process "xyz"
    button "Finish" of UI element 1 of scroll area 1 of window "abc" of application process "xyz"

Java code used:

```
List<String> items = Arrays.asList(resultObject.toString().split("\\s*,\\s*"));
List<String> formattedList = new ArrayList<String>();
for (String item : items) {
    formattedList.add(item);                        
}
```

Expected Output:
similar to string but in four different list objects

```
item1 : button 1 of window "abc" of application process "xyz"
item2 :button 2 of window "abc" of application process "xyz"
item3: button 3 of window "abc" of application process "xyz"
item4 :button "Finish" of UI element 1 of scroll area 1 of window "abc" of application process "xyz"
```

Comment: What is the output you desire? What output do you get?

Comment: Expected Output:
similar to string but in four different list objects

Comment: thanks for ur suggestion. que is updtaed nw..

Answer (score 0):

Don't know how's that `resultObject` is constructed, but what you really need is a `String.split("\\r?\\n")`.

Btw I think your regexp is broken, that's why you get a single element in the output (it cannot be matched on the input). If you change it to `\\s+`, it will split your whole input for words. That's why you need the endlines there.

Answer (score 0):

If your input string is

> button 1 of window "abc" of application process "xyz" button 2 of window "abc" of application process "xyz" button 3 of window "abc" of application process "xyz" button "Finish" of UI element 1 of scroll area 1 of window "abc" of application process "xyz"

then you don't have a clear delimiter of the strings. The last item is not consistent with the first three (not the same pattern). What kind of object is `resultObject` and what does it produce? It would be helpful to post your input data.

If you want to split the string above you can try this:

```
String resultObject = new String("button 1 of window \"abc\" of application process \"xyz\" button 2 of window \"abc\" of application process \"xyz\" button 3 of window \"abc\" of application process \"xyz\" button \"Finish\" of UI element 1 of scroll area 1 of window \"abc\" of application process \"xyz\"");
String[] list = resultObject.toString().split("\"xyz\"");
for (String item : list) {                       
    System.out.println(item.trim());
}
```

It outputs:

```
button 1 of window "abc" of application process
button 2 of window "abc" of application process
button 3 of window "abc" of application process
button "Finish" of UI element 1 of scroll area 1 of window "abc" of application process
```

Or see [this link](http://ideone.com/LbIJyf).

Comment: cant we go with the app process "xyz" as delimitter?? since that remains common at the end??

Comment: Well, yes, if that never changes. I did look like some arbitrary text though.

Comment: Can you paste what resultObject.toString() returns?

Comment: it returns the same mentioned string in the que like String: button 1 of window "abc" of application process "xyz" button 2 of window "abc" of application process "xyz" button 3 of window "abc" of application process "xyz" button "Finish" of UI element 1 of scroll area 1 of window "abc" of application process "xyz